# How can i access to property of some directive from another directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have one directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirOne]',
  exportAs: 'appDirOne'
})
export class DirOneDirective {
  status: boolean = false;
  constructor() { }
}
```

in my other directive - when i click on the hosted element in my case the button i want to access to the property value of the first directive.

```
  <button appDirTwo>Btn</button>
```

**SECOND DIRECTIVE**

```
import { DirOneDirective } from './dir-one.directive';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirTwo]',
  exportAs: 'appDirTwo'
})
export class DirTwoDirective {
  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    // access to the status property value of the directiveOne
  }

}
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

i tried adding it in the constructor

```
import { DirOneDirective } from './dir-one.directive';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirTwo]',
  exportAs: 'appDirTwo'
})
export class DirTwoDirective {
  constructor(private directiveOne: DirOneDirective) { }
  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
  }

}
```

but i get

`core.js:4197 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[DirOneDirective -> DirOneDirective -> DirOneDirective]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for DirOneDirective!`

error.

I want to mention that both of the directives are in my `app.module.ts` file.

If i try to use my directiveOne in HTML for example

```
  <button appDirOne>Btn</button>
```

then i don't have this provider error message.
This happens only when i try to inject as service in the other directives.

Comment: Basically, you need a service if you want to share data between directives.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to consider another approach for this . For example, please read the official doc about the [passing inputs to an attribute directives](http://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#passing-values-into-an-attribute-directive) or leverage the services approach.

But back to our question. This is really **bad advice**, but you can import your `DirOneDirective` to the `DirTwoDirective` and create an instance of `DirOneDirective` for example in the `constructor` of `DirTwoDirective`. Something like:

**First directive:**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  status: boolean = false;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
}
```

**The second directive:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HighlightDirective } from './highlight.directive';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighweight]'
})
export class HighweightDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    const highLDir = new HighlightDirective(this.el);
    console.log(highLDir.status); // false
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwj1ex?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhighlight.directive.ts)

Comment: Never create a directive or a component by using new, and definitely not to solve the op's question.

Comment: I have written that thus is the bad advice and op need another approach.